# After Svelte/Sapper app delopy on Heroku 404 The requested page could not be found

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, svelte

I have a Svelte app deployed to Heroku. This is a legacy code, at first I had 500 error, but after I installed serve the 500 error is gone, but I get the abovementioned 404. I have created another folder on my computer and pulled this very app from Heroku with heroku git:clone -a , ran npm install and it works like a charm locally. I do not get any errors in the console nor in my IDE. I found solutions saying that pushing my build folder can help, but so I did and nothing.
Would someone please pint me to the proper solution, this is my package.json, if necessary I will provide other data.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "x",
  "description": "y",
  "version": "2.0.111",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm version patch && git push && git push --tags",
    "deploy": "git push -f heroku master",
    "heroku-postbuild": "run-p build",
    "dev": "sapper dev",
    "build": "sapper build --legacy",
    "export": "sapper export --legacy",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "test": "run-p --race dev cy:run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "polka": "next",
    "serve": "^12.0.0",
    "sirv": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rollup": "^1.12.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.1.1",
    "sapper": "^0.27.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:confrontjs/2019.confrontjs.com.git"
  }
}
```

Thanks!